# Non-trivial compatibility which makes convex functions continuous on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Here are the definitions:

Let $X$ be a set. Another set $\mathcal C\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is called a *convexity* over $X$ if

- $\varnothing, X\in\mathcal C$
- $\mathcal C$ is closed under arbitrary intersections
- $\mathcal C$ is closed under arbitrary *nested* unions (that is, a union of a chain from $\mathcal C$ [w.r.t. subset inclusion] is in $\mathcal C$)

The pair $(X,\mathcal C)$ is called a *convex space*, and the elements of $\mathcal C$ are called the *convex subsets* of $X$.

Given two convex spaces $(X,\mathcal C_1)$ and $(Y,\mathcal C_2)$, a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called *convexity preserving*, or simply *convex*, if for every convex set of $Y$ its preimage under $f$ is a convex subset of $X$.

The standard convexity over the real numbers is, unsurprisingly, the set of convex subsets. If the definition is required, a subset $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ is called convex if for all $x$ and $y\in S$ and any $\lambda\in[0,1]$ we also have that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in S$.

---

My question is based on the observation that a convex function over $\Bbb R$ is also continuous.

Abstractly, given two sets $X_1, X_2$; two topologies $\mathcal T_1, \mathcal T_2$; and two convexities $\mathcal C_1, \mathcal C_2$; there doesn't seem to be any reason that a convex function $f:(X_1,\mathcal C_1)\rightarrow (X_2,\mathcal C_2)$ should also be continuous as a function from $(X_1,\mathcal T_1)$ to $(X_2,\mathcal T_2)$. If this is the case, I'd expect that $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal C_1$ satisfy some non-trivial relation (same for $\mathcal T_2$ and $\mathcal C_2$).

> Is there a compatibility between the canonical topology and the canonical convexity of $\Bbb R$ which implies that all convex functions are continuous?

I don't really want a proof that convex implies continuous, unless you're using it to exemplify the possible relation.

Any help is appreciated, as always.

Comment: I'm mystified. If $P$ is true, then $A$ *implies* $P$ no matter what the set of propositions $A$. Presumably you're asking for the conditions $A$ needed to *prove* "$f$ convex implies $f$ continuous", but you say you already have that proof. You can see what facts about $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ are used in the proof. So what are you looking for that you can't get by inspecting the proof?

Comment: Proofs can obfuscate what's really at work. For example, you can prove that the open sets of $\Bbb R$ are countable disjoint unions of open intervals without topology. But without the language from topology, it would be hard to grok that the properties of $\Bbb R$ that make this true is that $\Bbb R$ is locally connected and ccc. I'm betting that there's some correlation between the topology and convexity of $\Bbb R$ that gives us this result, but I'm not seeing it by inspecting the proof. It might even generalize to abstract topological and convexity spaces.

Comment: Your definition of "convex function" seems very strange and does not imply continuity. In fact, a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ appears to be "convex" according to your definition iff it is monotone.